# How do I select text in dynamically added input box when parent div has onclick handler?

Tags: javascript, html

I have code similar to this:

```
<div id="div1" onclick="myfunc()">
    <span class="myspan"></span>
</div>
```

Now, if a user clicks on a button elsewhere on the page, an input box is dynamically added to the span. The button also gives the input box focus.

The input box has code like this:

```
<input type=text onkeypress="runthis()" onblur="runthis()">
```

The problem is, if I try to select text in the input box, the parent onclick and onblur fire. I want to edit the input box until I click away (or hit enter).

This is basically a quick edit box. A user clicks an edit button, the input box appears. They click out or hit enter and it saves.

Edit (actual code):

```
<div class="plBoxContainer">
<a href="playlists" onClick="playlists(id); return false;" onMouseOver="if(RUNPLAYLIST){this.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.textDecoration='underline'}" onMouseOut="this.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.textDecoration='none'">
<br><span class="folderName">Some Name</span>
<span class="plEdit" onClick="PlEditBox(this.previousSibling); document.getElementById('dummydiv').innerHTML=id;">&nbsp;</span>
Some text</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function PlEditBox(folderName){
    RUNPLAYLIST = 0;
    name = folderName.innerHTML;
    folderName.innerHTML = '<input type=text id="folderNameChange" value="'+name+'" onkeypress="return PlDoEdit(this.value, document.getElementById(\'dummydiv\').innerHTML, event);" onBlur="PlDoEdit(this.value, document.getElementById(\'dummydiv\').innerHTML, \'blur\')">';
    document.getElementById('folderNameChange').focus();
    document.getElementById('folderNameChange').select();
}

function PlDoEdit(value, id, e)
{
    var keycode;
    if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    else if (e && e != blur) keycode = e.which;
    else keycode = '';

    if (keycode == 13 || e == 'blur')
    {
        RUNPLAYLIST = 1;
        //do some unrelated stuff here
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

function playlists(plID) 
{
    if(RUNPLAYLIST==0)
    {
            RUNPLAYLIST = 1;
            return false;
    }
    //do a bunch of unrelated stuff here
}
```

Comment: What are the "parent onclick and onblur" handlers? Which "parent" do you mean? There is no other onblur handler except the one on the `input` itself.

Comment: I meant parent onclick and input box onblur

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use event.returnValue = false/event.preventDefault in your function to prevent event bubling. Like

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```

For more see [http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/DOMEvent#Event:stop](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/DOMEvent#Event%3astop)

Comment: +1 because this will work, but you may not want to prevent event propagation. You can also have `myFunc()` do nothing unless #div1 is the actual event target. Heera's answer requires some event normalization. You may want to consider using a framework to abstract that away. I have a solution that uses YUI, but JSFiddle isn't allowing saves at the moment so I can't link to it. :(

Comment: Thanks. I think you misread, I asked where to put the code.  I already have myFunc returning in this case but it still won't allow me to select text and the onblur still fires. I tried changing the z-index for the text box style but that didn't help. 

I guess this is because the input box is in the div itself.

Comment: I didn't misread. I'm just offering an alternative to Heera's method. You also can't toss that code into a method directly as it lacks the event normalization. If you want his method to work, you'll need to add an event parameter to runthis() (e.g. runthis(e)) and add "e = e || window.event", then Heera's: "e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;". Kind of hard to read in a comment, eh? :P

Comment: Codes should be placed in runthis(e){...} function and follow Brendan's approach. I've gave you only the core idea. Thanks Brendan!

Answer (score 1):

JS Fiddle isn't allowing saving/sharing at the moment as they are migrating their servers. In the mean time, there's a screenshot at the bottom of this post that might help.

It looks like you're using pure Javascript, but I used YUI to abstract away the even normalization; nobody should be bothered with that! :)

Basically the event handler for the DIV element won't actually do anything unless the DIV is the true even target (i.e. the DIV was clicked directly rather than the INPUT within).

(**Right-click > View Image** in Firefox to see full size.)
[image: JS Fiddle of solution]

### Update

I made another JS Fiddle that displays a name, turns it into an edit box if you click on it, and saves the value (returning to simple display) when the INPUT loses focus or when ENTER key is pressed.

(**Right-click > View Image** in Firefox to see full size.)
[image: JS Fiddle 2 of solution]

Comment: thanks. It looks like you are basically doing a return in myfunc. I am also doing this (although it is return false;) It still triggers the input box onblur method.

Comment: I don't think I understand your requirements properly. If you don't want `runthis()` to do anything when you blur the input by clicking the `<div>`, then you can do a similar target detection (i.e. `if (e.target === Y.one("#div1")) { return; }`) in the body of `runthis()`.

Comment: if I click the div, I want it to runthis(). But if I click within the input box, I want to be able to select text without runthis() firing.

Comment: This is basically a quick edit box. A user clicks an edit button, the input box appears. They click out or hit enter and it saves.

Comment: The `onblur` event shouldn't fire when you select text inside an input. In my screenshot example, running on Firefox 9.0.1, `runthis()` only fires when something is typed in the input box, or when it truly loses focus (not when text is selected). The `onclick` even for the DIV only fires when the DIV itself is clicked (not its children). If you are getting different behavior, you should provide your source and what browser you're running it on.

Comment: I updated my original post with the actual code. Its a big complicated app so I extracted as much as I thought was related to the problem. Thanks again. (I am on firefox currently but have other browsers available)

Comment: I updated my answer with a new JS Fiddle which does a quick-edit box. It only uses a blur event. I see that you've now updated your question with your source, but I'm not sure I will have time to look at it tonight. As usual, I'm leveraging the power of YUI, so I hope it's useful to you. (If you want to duplicate the Fiddle, load YUI 3.4.1 using onDomReady in the left menu.)